# Write values into different text files for different keys scala

Tags: scala

I have map with (keys, list(values)). i want to write list(values) into different files on the basis of different keys.
for Example
(1,List(a,b,c,d))
(2,List(x,y,z))
so, i want to write key 1 values into file1.txt 
and key 2 values into file2.txt

```
class ScalaClass(val ccFilePath: String) {

  val sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm")
  val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")
  def hello() {

    var counter = 1

    val inputFiles = new java.io.File("D:\\IntelliHub MDMS\\CC files\\xml file and Cdata\\cc\\File Import for triggering AU2.csv")
    val iBufferSource = Source.fromFile(inputFiles)
    val iData = iBufferSource.getLines().toArray
    var lpDate = ""
    val result = scala.io.Source.fromFile(ccFilePath)
      .getLines
      .filter(line => ((iData).contains(line.split(",")(1))))
      .map { lines =>
        {
          (formatter.format(sf.parse(lines.split(",")(2))), lines)
        }
      }
      .toList
      .groupBy(_._1).map(p => p._1 -> p._2.map(_._2)).toMap
      .foreach {
        case (key, value) =>

          // println (key + "-->" + value)
          val fileName = new File("D:\\IntelliHub MDMS\\CC files\\xml file and Cdata\\hkincoming\\NORMAL\\AD1\\AU2_dump" + counter + ".dat")
          var pw = new java.io.PrintWriter(fileName)
          try
            if (fileName.exists()) {
              counter + 1
              pw = new java.io.PrintWriter("D:\\IntelliHub MDMS\\CC files\\xml file and Cdata\\hkincoming\\NORMAL\\AD1\\AU2_dump" + counter + ".dat")
              pw.write(value.mkString("\n"))
            } else {
              pw.write(value.mkString("\n"))
            }
          finally pw.flush()
          pw.close()
      }
  }
}
```

This is my current code where i m reading two files, filtering records on the basis of meterID and creating a map(key, List(values)) using groupBy.
Key = Date
Values = lines.

while using above code i m getting only one file which having latest record.
When i printed the map, i saw i have around 20 keys. so i need data into 20 different text files.

Input file 1 format

```
MO/5052497_A+CON_kWh,5052497,2018/03/17 00:00,8,2,AMI,0.0020,CON_kWh,-1
MO/5052497_A+CON_kWh,5052497,2018/03/17 00:30,8,2,AMI,0.0020,CON_kWh,-1
MO/5052497_A+CON_kWh,5052497,2018/03/17 01:00,8,2,AMI,0.0020,CON_kWh,-1
```

Input File 2 has only MeterID which needs to be match in file 1 and get results on the basis of date as key.

Input File 2 format

```
5053610,5053688,5053689
```

I m new to scala. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `pw.append` instead of `pw.write`

Comment: @roterl thanks i tried but still getting only one file with data of only one key.

Comment: Can you provide example of the input files and the expected result?

Comment: @roterl updated my question with two input files.

Comment: try this `val a = List((1,List("a","b","c","d")), (2,List("x","y","z")))` 
`import java.io._
a.map({x=>  val pw = new PrintWriter("file"+x._1+".txt")
pw.write(x._2.mkString("\n"))
pw.close()
})`

Comment: @Yogesh thanks alot. it worked.i m getting multiples files on the basis of keys :)

Comment: I honestly find it hard to understand what do you expect to get. but I see you done increase the counter `counter  = counter + 1`

Comment: @roterl sorry for my language. Actually counter = counter + 1 was to write a new file with different name. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate.

Comment: @ArvindPant I am guessing you have managed to solve your issue with 2 changes suggested by roterl. If yes, can you please close the question ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I was able to solve my issue using Yogesh's solution. yes i m closing the question.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh  I think i dnt have enough reputation to close this ticket. i couldn't see any option to close the ticket.

Comment: You can just delete the question in that case. Since you are the creator, you can definitely do it.